# Get a list of table column names and values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which have some fields and values. I am trying to get a list of table column names and values (column name-value pairs).

For example, I have below table with fields and values:

MyTable:

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 .... FieldN
 89      34     10          233
```

So I want to get below table (field name - field value pair):

```
FieldName  FieldValue
Field1     89
Field2     34
Field3     10
...
FieldN     233
```

I mean a table with two fields: FieldName as text and FieldValue as number.

To get a list of table column names I perform below:

```
SELECT NAME  FROM  sys.columns  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('schema.MyTable')
```

but I do not know how to obtain the value for each column name. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by column name-value pairs? What is value here

Comment: Perhaps you want the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` DMV?

Comment: @PraneetNadkar I have updated my post, I mean I want to get a table with two fields: FieldName and FieldValue.  See my update.

Comment: @Lamu See my update.

Comment: This is already answered here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468196/sql-convert-single-row-to-key-value-columns

Comment: @PraneetNadkar The problem with this approach is that you must explicitly specify the columns of the table: val FOR Col IN ([Col 1], [Col 2], [Col 3]) My table have 65 columns so is there another way to use in the IN CLAUSE the select from my query: SELECT NAME  FROM  sys.columns  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('schema.MyTable')  ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dynamic query to use columns dynamically and need to make column's size same to resolve the issue `Column conflicts with the type of other columns in the unpivot list`. I found it very tedious though it's very useful in your case

```
CREATE TABLE test (Field1 INT, Field2 INT, Field3 INT, FieldN INT, flag CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(89,34,10,233, 'i')

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
    @colIn NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
    @colSelect NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT 
@colIn += ', ' + QUOTENAME(name),
@colSelect += ',' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ')'
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('test')

SET @sql = '
SELECT a.FieldName, a.FieldValue
FROM (SELECT ' + STUFF(@colSelect, 1, 1, '') + '
    FROM test) t
UNPIVOT([FieldValue] FOR [FieldName] IN (' + STUFF(@colIn, 1, 1, '') + ')) a '

EXEC(@sql)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
FieldName   FieldValue
Field1      89
Field2      34
Field3      10
FieldN      233
flag        i
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want, but the problem with this approach, as said to @Praneet (he provided a link to an idem solution) is that you must to explicitly specify the columns in the IN-CLAUSE. My table has 65 columns so If I need to explicitly specify all the 65 columns in the IN-CLAUSE...Is it possible to put in the in-clause the result obtained from the select SELECT NAME  FROM  sys.columns  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('schema.MyTable') ?

Comment: Also If you have an script with this query, when you add new fields to the table, you need to modify this to explicitly indicate the new fields added to the table...

Comment: Also it seems like all the fields in this approach must be of the same type if not below error message is thrown: Column conflicts with the type of other columns in the unpivot list

Comment: @Susang, nice answer. If a column has no value = NULL, then it is not listed. Is it possible to list those columns as well ?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to generate a dynamic statement using `UNPIVOT`. If your columns are from different data types, use `CONVERT`:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   ColumnVarchar varchar(100),
   ColumnDateTime datetime,
   ColumnInt int
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (ColumnVarchar, ColumnDateTime, ColumnInt)
VALUES
   ('Some text 1', GETDATE(), 1)
```

Statement:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @names nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @values nvarchar(max)

-- Dynamic part 
SELECT 
   @values = STUFF((
      SELECT CONCAT(N', CONVERT(varchar(max), ', QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME]), N') AS ', QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME]))
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Data'
      FOR XML PATH('')
   ), 1, 1, N''),
   @names = STUFF((
      SELECT CONCAT(N', ', QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME]))
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Data'
      FOR XML PATH('')
   ), 1, 1, N'')

-- Whole statement and execution
SELECT @stm = 
   CONCAT(
      N'SELECT u.FieldName, u.FieldValue FROM (SELECT',
      @values,
      N'FROM Data) d UNPIVOT ([FieldValue] FOR [FieldName] IN (',
      @names,
      N')) u')
EXEC (@stm)
```

Output:

```
-----------------------------------
FieldName       FieldValue
-----------------------------------
ColumnVarchar   Some text 1
ColumnDateTime  Apr 29 2019  1:45PM
ColumnInt       1
```

Update - save results into different table:

```
-- Whole statement and execution
SELECT @stm = 
   CONCAT(
      N'SELECT u.FieldName, u.FieldValue INTO ResultTable FROM (SELECT',
      @values,
      N'FROM Data) d UNPIVOT ([FieldValue] FOR [FieldName] IN (',
      @names,
      N')) u')
EXEC (@stm)

SELECT * 
FROM ResultTable
```

Comment: Nice! but how can I put all this within a CTE and then reuse this output for the rest of queries? I would like to do the same but within a CTE.

Comment: @user1624552 If I understand correctly - insert results into different table (updated answer). Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov, somehow the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is not resulting in anything while `sys.columns` in the other answer does. Do you know if something specific has to be activated to make `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` work as well ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` just *returns one row for each column that can be accessed by the current user in the current database*.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada If you want, replace `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Data'` with `SELECT c.[name] FROM sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id WHERE t.[name] = 'Addition'`. Just replace `COLUMN_NAME` with `c.[name]` and `TABLE_NAME` with `t.[name]`

Comment: @Zhorov yeah thanks. with the last comment then we're back to the other answer. and regarding `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` I assume it is permissions related. but thanks anyway... +1 at least from my side...